# Pin unlock without showing numbers

Tags: lock-screens, security

When you type your pin into the Android lock screen, it does the usual mobile password field thing where it actually shows the last character you've entered.

Is there any way to disable this on vanilla Android 4.4? As in show only dots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I just upgrade to 5.0/Lollipop, I can't confirm for sure if this setting is present in KitKat/4.4, but in 5.0, you can hide the last digit in the PIN unlock screen by turning off the Security setting labeled **Make passwords visible**, as seen here:

[image]

This is found under the general **Settings** app under the **Security** section.  Note, however, that this also affects password fields elsewhere in Android, such as in the Chrome browser.

Comment: I remember that it's there since I already used this feature in Jelly Bean.

Comment: This is also a setting for Android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

I have Android 14. Derek's answer did solve the problem on websites and such, but not on the PIN lock screen. I still see the numbers being typed there. Huge numbers visible from far far away.

For that to be fixed, go to Settings / Security & lock screen / Screen lock *(cogwheel)* / **Enhanced PIN privacy**. Turn it on.